# change text color with mix-blend-mode when divs are overlapping

Tags: javascript, css

I have a circular div which follows my cursor. When this div overlaps some text on my page, I want the color of the text to change. I know this is possible with `mix-blend-mode` like in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/10/), but I just can't get it to work.
I tried `backdrop-filter` and different approaches with SVG but none of it will work.
I've seen this effect on so many sites, but I just can't figure it out myself.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/AgathaKing/pen/PoZExKz)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not showing because your `text`'s color and `circle`'s color are same. Change your `label`'s css into the [**`codepen`**](https://codepen.io/AgathaKing/pen/PoZExKz) like this. It will be shown.

```css
.label
  color: red
  font-size: 28px
  z-index: 2
  mix-blend-mode: difference
```